# What is the behaviour of Webpack 1 in regards to the browser field in package.json?

Tags: npm, webpack, runtime-error, package.json

How does Webpack v1 treat the `browser` field in an installed package's `package.json`. I can't find any documentation for this anywhere.

I am using Gatsby.js which used Webpack v1 for compilation. One of the packages I'm using uses the `browser` field in its `package.json` and points it to some untranspiled ES6 code.

As far as I can see Webpack is compiling this code (instead of the transpiled code pointed to by the `lib` field) into `commons.js`, resulting in runtime errors because of the ES6 import/export declarations.

My problem is that the problematic package is a dependency of another package which I must use. The only solution I've found so far is to remove the `browser` field from the package's `package.json`, but obviously this is not a workable answer going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config setting can be found in `resolve.packageMains` ([docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-packagemains)) which has been renamed to `resolve.mainFields` ([docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields)) as of Webpack 2+.

The behaviour is that the `browser` field will be used if present, but can be overridden using `resolve.packageAlias`.